# Transaction not complete for two days now

Tags: transactions, blockchain, client, unconfirmed-transactions, confirmations

I sent bitcoins to a wallet using the QR code in order to be very sure of the address. It shows in my wallet that it has been sent. But the receiver haven't seen it in his wallet. I checked it online and it shows that the money is in the address.  How can i do for him to see his coins or if not get?
I sent it to this address.
Note: the transaction shows confirmed

1N9V3yNuBEbgS3g87qibrnTGARj9SrKFst

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)

Answer (score 1):

1N9V3yNuBEbgS3g87qibrnTGARj9SrKFst did receive bitcoins. If they ask you to send again, don't, it might be a scam.

You can give them the transaction ids:

```
170e84bcc871f4cca8d352035c4bbe9e1a44bf2f66c8e9e4ff69547ea1256639
d1b5b5fddfde0aa492f8ef8a58f6740222ceed42d2ee369082ea4e95f7233415
```

even though they don't need them. You can just tell them "on [block explorers](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/address/1N9V3yNuBEbgS3g87qibrnTGARj9SrKFst) it the transactions are shown as confirmed." with a kind "Can you confirm that the output address 1N9V3yNuBEbgS3g87qibrnTGARj9SrKFst shown on the block explorer was the one you had given to me?"